# Show random background image by ID JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, background-image

I ran into this little fiddle here but I simply can't figure out how to place `ID="something"` instead of `DIV` for the JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/EyKZZ/

Comment: Something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/EyKZZ/49/)**?

Comment: What element on the web page does have this ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the id something to your div and add the javasscript with "#something" in the jquery selector.

CSS:

```
#something {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

JQuery selector:

```
$("#something").css("background", "url(" + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ")");
```

Set id to the div:

```
<div id="something"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/EyKZZ/48/)

Comment: yea but the images are broken thou, after inspecting it doesnt pull the pics :/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<div id="something"></div>
```

and in javascript part

```
$("#something").css("background", "url(" + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ")");
```